# How to get correct PDF metadata?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf, classicthesis, metadata

I am having trouble getting the PDF metadata to be created. I tried using the code below but the metadata is not created.

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,
            pdfauthor={nxkryptor},
            pdftitle={Lorem ipsum},
            pdfsubject={ME},
            pdfkeywords={},
            pdfproducer={Latex with hyperref, or other system},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex, or other tool}]{hyperref}

\graphicspath
    { 
    {Figures/}
    }

\begin{document}
\title{\rmfamily\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Title}}
\author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Lorem Ipsum}}
\date{} % no date

\maketitle
\section*{This is a section}
This is just a metadata test
\end{document}
```

How can I create the PDF metadata?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: To start: `15pt` is no valid option for `article`. Remove the font commands from `\author` and `\title` (they do not belong there).

Comment: You load `hyperref` twice, which is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 8):

`classicthesis` already loads `hyperref`, so you have to use `\hypersetup` to set the metadata (Hint: do not use `pdftex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={nxkryptor},
            pdftitle={Lorem ipsum},
            pdfsubject={ME},
            pdfkeywords={},
            pdfproducer={Latex with hyperref, or other system},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex, or other tool}
            }

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Lorem Ipsum}
\date{} % no date

\maketitle
\section*{This is a section}
This is just a metadata test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, i overlooked your answer. Please add a hint not to load option `pdftex`, i'll remove my answer.

Comment: Done ;) *Hint, hint*